# How should I share workbooks that use PowerPivot?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, powerpivot

I've used powerpivot to make a super-awesome report. But now I need to share it with my co-workers, who do not use powerpivot.

When I send someone a powerpivot report to users without powerpivot installed, none of the controls work--you can't expand a field, you can't click on a slicer, etc.

What's the best way to do this? Is there a way to convert a powerpivot table to a regular pivot table that excel can understand?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you do not have powerpivot installed you will only be able to see the data at the state it was in when the workbook was saved. None of the controls will work (since using the controls will basically attempt to invoke powerpivot to query the underlying data data).

This MSDN article mentions a few options you might consider: [MSDN: Ways To Share PowerPivot Workbook](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d810eaf1-f24e-4ca1-9ed8-cb01e40432db/ways-to-share-the-power-pivot-workbook?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel)